# Is it possible to build complex animations with react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-animatable

[image]

Is it possible to build a splashscreen with the given design using react-native ?

Comment: Yeah. Wrap your Text component with `Animated.View` and interpolate on translateX values.

Comment: You can convert this animation into Gif or video and can play it on splash screen